Determining the multiplication via addition and some unary operation
It is known that the addition operation in a skew-field $F$ (more generally, in a quasifield) is uniquely determined by the multiplication operation and the unary involutive  operation $1_{-}:F\to F$, $1_-:x\mapsto 1-x$.
This shows that all information about the structure of a skew-field is encoded in its multiplicative group and the involution $1_-$.

Question. Is there some simple (desirably involutive) unary operation that uniquely determines the multiplication via addition in skew-fields (or better in quasi-fields)? In other words: can the multiplicative operation of a quasi-field be encoded by the addition and some unary operation?

This question is especially interesting for finite quasi-field. In infinite sets unary operations can encode anything.
Remark. For a field of characteristic $\ne 2$ such a unary involutive operation is $\underline{1}:F^*\to F^*$, $\underline{1}:x\mapsto \frac 1x$, where $F^*:=F\setminus\{0\}$.
Indeed, for any $x\in F\setminus\{0,1\}$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\frac1{x}+\frac1{1-x}}=\frac1{\frac{1-x}{x(1-x)}+\frac{x}{x(1-x)}}=\frac{x(1-x)}{(1-x)+1}=x-x^2$$and hence
$$x^2=x-\frac1{\frac1x+\frac1{1-x}}.$$So, the square operation $F\to F$, $F:x\mapsto x^2$, is expressible via the addition and multiplicative inverse. In its turn, the multiplication is expressible via the addition and the square operation by the well-known formula:
$$xy=\frac{(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2}2.$$However this approach does not work for fields of characteristic 2 and also for skew-fields: every skew-field $(F,+,\cdot)$ and its antiisomorphic copy endowed with the multiplication $x*y:=y\cdot x$ have the same unary operation of multiplicative inverse. So, the multiplication operation of a skew-field cannot be uniquely recovered from the operation of addition and the unary operation of multiplicative inverse. But maybe some other (involutive) unary operation will do the job?

can the multiplicative operation of a quasi-field
be encoded by the addition and some unary operation? $\ldots$
This question is especially interesting for
finite quasi-field. In infinite sets unary
operations can encode anything.
The word 'encoded' is ambiguous. I will interpret
'be encoded by the addition and some unary operation'
to mean
'be a term function in the language of addition,
constant $1$, and some unary function'.
This is a very restrictive interpretation, but it
is possible to say nontrivial things
under this interpretation.
Remarks.
I. Let $\mathbb F_2 = \langle \{0,1\}; +,-,0,\cdot, 1\rangle$
be the $2$-element field.
Let $(\mathbb F_2)^u = \langle \{0,1\}; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
for some unary operation $u\colon \{0,1\}\to \{0,1\}$.
Since the universe of $\mathbb F_2$ is so small,
the only choices for $u$ are:
a constant function, the identity function,
or $x\mapsto 1-x$. In particular, every possible unary function
on $\{0,1\}$ is a term function of the pointed abelian group
$\langle \{0,1\}; +,-,0, 1\rangle$.
This implies that every operation of $(\mathbb F_2)^u$
preserves the $4$-ary relation $R\subseteq \{0,1\}^4$
consisting of all tuples with an even number of $1$'s.
The multiplication of $\mathbb F_2$ does not preserve this relation $R$,
since $(1,1,0,0), (1,0,1,0)\in R$ but their product is not in $R$.
Since $R$ is preserved by addition and all unary functions
on $\{0,1\}$, but $R$ is not preserved by multiplication,
there are senses of the word 'encoded' for which the answer
to this question is No. For example, this argument shows
that multiplication cannot be expressed as a term
function of $(\mathbb F_2)^u$ for any choice of $u$.
II. It follows from Remark I that multiplication cannot be
expressed as a term
function of $\mathbb Q^u = \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
for any quasifield $\mathbb Q$ of characteristic $2$
and for any unary function $u\colon Q\to Q$
satisfying $u(\{0,1\})\subseteq \{0,1\}$.
For, if $m(x,y)$ were such a term function,
then $m(x,y)$ could be restricted to $\{0,1\}\subseteq Q$
and we would recover the multiplication of $\mathbb F_2$
as a term function of $\langle \{0,1\}; +,-,0,u|_{\{0,1\}}, 1\rangle$,
contrary to Remark I. I think this hints at why characteristic $2$
is different than other characteristics for this problem.
III. On the other hand,
for any finite quasifield
$\mathbb Q = \langle Q; +,-,0,\cdot, 1\rangle$
which has MORE than $2$ elements,
it IS possible to express the multiplication operation of $\mathbb Q$
as a term function of $\mathbb Q^u = \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
provided $u\colon \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ is chosen well.
In fact, if $|Q|>2$, it is possible to find $u\colon \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$
so that $\mathbb Q^u$ is a $\textit{primal}$ algebra.
(Saying that $\mathbb Q^u$ is primal means that
every finitary operation on the universe $Q$ is a term
function of the algebra. If every function on the universe
is a term function, then of course the
quasifield multiplication is a term function.)

Here is how I would choose $u(x)$ in order to
ensure that $\mathbb Q^u$ is primal.
First note that the kernel of a finite
quasifield $\mathbb Q$ is a finite subfield
and that $\mathbb Q$ is a vector space over this subfield.
The fact that $\mathbb Q$ contains a subfield
implies that $\mathbb Q$ is additively
an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$.
Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ be a basis
for the additive reduct of $\mathbb Q$.
We may assume that $e_1 = 1_{\mathbb Q}$.
Define $u\colon Q\to Q$ so that it cyclically permutes
the elements of the tuple $(0,e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_k)$
and so that $u(q)=0$ if $q\in Q-\{0,1,e_2,\ldots,e_k)$.
I claim that $\mathbb Q^u = \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
is primal, so in particular the
quasifield multiplication of $\mathbb Q$
is a term function of $\langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$.
I will apply a primality criterion due to Ralph McKenzie.
(He stated it for Mal'cev algebras,
but I will state a slightly simpler form
for expansions of groups, which is a specialization
of his criterion).
Primality Criterion. An expansion $\mathbb A$
of a finite (not-necessarily-abelian)
group $\langle A; +, -, 0\rangle$
is primal iff $\mathbb A$ has no

 
proper subalgebra, 


proper, nontrivial congruence, 


nonidentity automorphism,


and $\mathbb A$ has an operation that fails to commute with
$x-y+z$.
Our algebra $\mathbb Q^u = \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
is an expansion of a group $\langle Q; +,-,0\rangle$.
Every element of $\mathbb Q^u$ is the interpretation of
a constant term, since (i) $0$ and $1$ are such, (ii) by applying $u$
repeatedly we see that $0, 1, e_2, \ldots, e_k$ are such,
and (iii) closing under sums shows that every element of $Q$ is such.
Any algebra where every element is the interpretation of a constant
term has no proper subalgebras and no nonidentity
automorphisms.
It is not hard to see that $u$ fails to commute with $x-y+z$
on the triple $(1,0,1)$ unless the characteristic of $\mathbb Q$ is $2$.
(That is, $u(1-0+1)\neq u(1)-u(0)+u(1)$ unless $\textrm{char}(\mathbb Q)=2$.
The left-hand side is zero and the right-hand side is not.)
If the characteristic is $2$, then
$u$ fails to commute with $x-y+z$
on the triple
$(e_1+e_2,e_2,0)$ provided the additive basis
for the elementary abelian $p$-group
$\langle Q; +,-,0,\rangle$
has size at least $2$.
The remaining case where the characteristic is $2$ and the size of the basis is $1$
does not occur, because we assumed that $|Q|>2$.
(We must exclude the possibility that $|Q|=2$ by the first remark.)
What remains to show is that
$\mathbb Q^u = \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
has no proper, nontrivial congruence.
Suppose that such a congruence $\theta$  existed.
Case 1. $0\equiv_{\theta} 1 \;(=e_1)$.
Reasoning: In this case,
$$0\equiv_{\theta}\; e_1 \Rightarrow e_1=u(0)\equiv_{\theta} u(e_1) = e_2
\Rightarrow e_2\equiv_{\theta} e_3\Rightarrow \textrm{etc},$$
so $0\equiv_{\theta}e_i$
for all $i$. This forces $\theta$ to be improper. \\\
Case 2. $0\not\equiv_{\theta} 1 \;(=e_1)$.
Reasoning: The congruence $\theta$ must partition $Q$
into cosets of some proper, nontrivial additive subgroup $H$
of the elementary abelian $p$-group
$\langle Q; +,-,0,\rangle$.
We must have $1\notin H$ because $0\not\equiv_{\theta} 1$.
If possible, choose $h\in H$
such that $u(h)=0$.
Since $h\in H$ we have $0\equiv_{\theta} h$,
so $1=u(0)\equiv_{\theta} u(h) = 0$.
This
is not possible in the case we are in, so $u$ cannot
vanish on $H$ in Case 2.
Because of this and the fact that $e_1=1\notin H$ in Case 2, we must
have that $H$ is an additive subgroup of
$\textrm{support}(u)-\{e_1\}=\{0,e_2,\ldots,e_{k-1}\}$.
The only additive subgroups of this set are
of the form $\{0,e_i\}$, $1<i<k$, and this can only
happen if $\textrm{char}(\mathbb Q) = 2$.
We now have $0\equiv_{\theta} e_i$, so
$0+1\equiv_{\theta} e_i+1$. Applying $u$ to both sides
of $0+1 \equiv_{\theta} e_i+1$
yields $(e_2 =)\; u(1)\equiv_{\theta} u(e_i+1) = 0$.
Thus, $H=\{0,e_2\}$. Starting with $0\equiv_{\theta} e_2$ and
repeatedly applying $u$ we derive that
$0\equiv_{\theta} e_2
\equiv_{\theta} e_4\equiv_{\theta} \cdots$
and
$1=e_1\equiv_{\theta} e_3
\equiv_{\theta} e_5\equiv_{\theta} \cdots$.
Thus, in the quotient $\mathbb Q/\theta$ all
basis elements reduce to $0$ or $1$, implying
that $H$ has index at most $2$ in the elementary abelian $2$-group
$\langle Q; +,-,0\rangle$. At the same time, $H=\{0,e_2\}$
has two elements,
so $|Q|\leq 4$.
Since $|Q|>2$ and $Q$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group,
we must have $Q = \{0, e_1, e_2, e_1+e_2\}$.
But this means that $e_2$ is the last basis
vector, so $u(e_2) = 0$, contrary to the earlier
conclusion that $u$ does not vanish on $H=\{0,e_2\}$.
This contradiction completes the argument for this case.

The two cases taken together suffice to show that
$\mathbb Q^u = \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$
has no nontrivial, proper congruence,
completing the proof that $\mathbb Q^u$
is primal. This yields that
the quasifield multiplication
(and every other finitary operation
on the set $Q$) is representable as
a term function of $\mathbb Q^u= \langle Q; +,-,0,u(x), 1\rangle$.

Thank you for your answer. Is there any (algorithmically) simple way of determining the multiplication as a term function in $(Q,+,-,0,u(x),1)$. My question was motivated by the (algorithmic) problem of determing the number of non-isomorphic quasifields of cardinality $32$. Can your answer help to resolve this algorithmic problem? Because the operation $u$ is in a sense fixed (and the number of binary operations is large, so some divesity should be hidden in ways of representations of the multiplication from the unary operation $u$).

@TarasBanakh: I responded to your comment elsewhere on this page.

This is a response to some questions raised by Taras Banakh
on my other answer on this page. Let me copy his questions here.
Thank you for your answer. Is there any (algorithmically) simple way of determining the multiplication as a term function in $(Q,+,-,0,u(x),1)$. My question was motivated by the (algorithmic) problem of determing the number of non-isomorphic quasifields of cardinality $32$. Can your answer help to resolve this algorithmic problem? Because the operation $u$ is in a sense fixed (and the number of binary operations is large, so some divesity should be hidden in ways of representations of the multiplication from the unary operation $u$).
The answer to your first question
(Is there any algorithmically simple way
of determining $\ldots$)
is No. In general, given a finite algebra with finitely
many basic operations, the problem of determining
whether some operation is a term function of the algebra
can be solved in exponential time by a brute force algorithm.
But the general problem of deciding if an operation
is a term function is EXP-time complete,
as was shown in:
Marcin Kozik
A finite set of functions with an EXPTIME-complete composition problem
Theoretical Computer Science
Volume 407, Issues 1-3, 6 November 2008, Pages 330-341
Regarding your second question
(Can your answer help to [determine the number of quasifields of order 32]?)
I think: No.
But now the goal of your question is clearer to me.
I think we are not close to knowing the number
of quasifields of order $n$ for $n\geq 32$.
I am not sure if you are looking for the exact number
or just an upper bound that is better than $n^{n^2}$.
It is known that the number of isomorphism types of loops
of size $n$ is smaller than the number
of unary functions $u\colon n\to n$
when $n\leq 7$, but
the number of isomorphism types of loops
of size $n$ is greater than the number
of unary functions $u\colon n\to n$
when $n=8, 9, 10$ (after which the number
of isomorphism types of loops is not known).
Hence you shouldn't expect to be able
to encode the set of isomorphism types
of loops into the the set of unary functions.
I suppose that not all loops arise
as the multiplicative loop of a quasifield,
but it is still reasonable to ask
whether the number of isomorphism types
of $n$-element quasifields exceeds the number
of unary functions $u\colon n\to n$, i.e. exceeds $n^n$ when $n$ is large.

Thank you for your answer. Indeed, not all loops arise as the multiplicative loop of a quasifield because every quasifield of order $n<9$ is a field, so its mutiplicative loop is just a cyclic group. On the other hand, every infinite loop arises as the multiplicatve loop of a suitable ternary-ring (I do not know whether this ternary-ring can be made q quasifield).

I am looking for the exact number of quasifields of order 32. So, this is just an algorithimic problem of enumerating all quasifields and then deciding how many of them are isomorphic. At the moment there are known only 9 non-isomorphic quasifields of order 32. So, my idea was to enumerate quasi-fields by a suitable unary operation. By the Hua Theorem, the unary operation of multiplicative inverse determines a skew-field (maybe even a semifield) up to an (anti)isomorphism. So, I hoped that some involutive opration also works for quasifields.

Observe that the number of involutive unary operations on a 30 element set is not very large: $30!/15!\approx 6\times 10^{20}$.
